# Error in my flutter project not showing in run tab

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-exception

When I get error, it showing in device but don't show in run tab I sure that it related to my project setting because my other project showing error in run tab
I need link error to the code, not just description.

I set module and SDK in project structure.

[image]